# jquery autoselect action on 'change' but not on 'select'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hope that made sense. I have a text input that uses the jQuery UI autoselect feature. The input auto-fills when a user selects, as it should. My problem is if a user inputs something, but then doesn't select from the drop down. This results in the text input value being something that doesn't exist in the list upon a form submit. I want to know if there is a way to perform an action (clear text input value) on the 'change' event but leave it as it is for the 'select' event.

Comment: What have you tried? Also: you know the issue, you know what's causing it, you have the code... what's stopping you?

Comment: You mean Autocomplete I believe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you should be able to leverage the `ui` parameter that's passed to a `change` event handler:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    /* options */
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }
});
```

`ui.item` will be `undefined` if nothing is selected from the autocomplete candidate list.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZBzpF/

Answer (score 0):

Inside the change event handler, check if the current value is in the source, if not, reset it. Something like:

```
var sourceArray = ["a", "b", "c"],
$autocomplete = $('#autocomplete');
$autocomplete.autocomplete({
    source: ,
    change: function(e, ui) {
        if ($.inArray($autocomplete.val(), sourceArray) === -1) {
            //change the value
        }
    })
}
```